# AngularJS: controller's function

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem using AngularJS in my application. Particularly, when I have to call a function that I have Written in controller part, it doesn't work.
Anyone knows how I have to proceed. Thanks.

This is my code... the function that gives me some problems is called totale().

```js
var app = angular.module('pizza', []);


app.controller('a1', function ($scope) {
    
    
    $scope.listino = [
         {id: 1, nom: 'Marinara', prezzo: 3.00},
         {id: 2, nom: 'Margherita', prezzo: 4.50},
         {id: 3, nom: '4 Formaggi', prezzo: 6.50},
         {id: 4, nom: 'Carbonara', prezzo: 6.00},
         {id: 5, nom: 'Boscaiola', prezzo: 7.00},
         {id: 6, nom: 'Patatosa', prezzo: 5.50},
         {id: 7, nom: 'Capricciosa', prezzo: 6.00},
    ];

      
    $scope.paste = [
        {n: 1, nome: 'Tradizionale'},
        {n: 2, nome: 'Integrale'}
    ];

    $scope.basi = [
        {n: 1, nome: 'Pomodoro', prezzo: 1.50},
        {n: 2, nome: 'Bianca',  prezzo: 0}
    ];

    $scope.ingredienti = [
        {n: 1, nome: 'Verdure', prezzo: 1.50, select: false},
        {n: 2, nome: 'Affettati',  prezzo: 1.85, select: false},
        {n: 3, nome: 'Funghi',    prezzo: 2.90, select: false},
        {n: 4, nome: 'Altri',  prezzo: 2, select: false}
    ];
    
    $scope.totale= function(){
        
        var tot=0;
        var sel = false;

        if ($scope.listino.val) {
            tot+=parseFloat($scope.listino.val);
        }

        if ($scope.basi.b) {
            tot+=parseFloat($scope.basi.b);
        }

        angular.forEach($scope.ingredienti, function (ingrediente) {
            if (ingrediente.selected) {
                tot += ingrediente.prezzo;
                sel = true;
            }
        });

        $scope.isDisabled = ($scope.paste.p || $scope.listino.val || $scope.basi.b || sel) ? false : true;

        return tot;
    };
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<button ng-click="$scope.ordine()" type="button" class="bottone btn btn-danger" ng-disabled="$scope.isDisabled">
                             Totale da pagare {{$scope.totale()}}€</button>
```

Comment: What does `it doesn't work` mean? What's the expected and actual behaviors?

Comment: That's not how binding works, that's not how any of this works. You don't use `$scope.` in binding. Swap to: `ng-click="ordine()"` and `ng-disabled="isDisabled"`. I don't even know what you wanted to do with `totale()`

Comment: With "totale()", I want to display user the total amount of money that he has to pay.

Comment: I have just solved the problem. Thanks to all!

Comment: @GGG How did you solved it?